# Lightbox2 - Back to beginning of slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 with print (http://sandbox.tse-webdesign.be/lightbox-print/).  I'd like to give the user the option within the lightbox effect to go back to the beginning on the slideshow.  Has anyone implemented anything like this?

Less ideal but perhaps easier if a button/link to go to the beginning of the slideshow is difficult - can I just wrap the show?  So when the user gets to image 10 or 10, clicking the next button will go to image 1 of 10?

Comment: can you post your code so far? I'd imagine you have a list of slides or something (or can create one) and keep track of the current slide and the total number of slides... If it's on the last slide, simply restart the counter.

Comment: The code is all posted on the site I linked in my question.  I don't think there is a counter to reset (not that I see anyway).  I could put a link to start the slide show over but I don't know how to get it into the actual lightbox effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a new modal in the JS file. Last image in slideshow would point back to the very first image of the gallery.

```
      //Go back home
  $lightbox.find('.lb-backhome').on('click', function(e) {
    _this.changeImage(0);
    console.log('back home link');
    return false;
  });
```

And

```
      if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
  }else{
    //Return this click index back to number one image
    $lightbox.find('.lb-backhome').show();
  }
```

Just update the entire my revised CSS and JS file and you'll be good to go.

My fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eguky/

## Per CC rules

Lightbox v2.51
by Lokesh Dhakar - http://www.lokeshdhakar.com

For more information, visit:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
- free for use in both personal and commercial projects
- attribution requires leaving author name, author link, and the license info intact

Comment: Not as ideal as having a link to go back to the first image but this is a nice solution to restart the slideshow.  Thanks for this!